# WF Designer re-hosting System.StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, workflow-foundation, activitydesigner

I need help with re-hosted designer of WF4. It should be used for design 
very complex workflow but there is limit of the nested activities. (It's 
around 40th nested activities in one branch). If is that limit exceeded, an 
System.StackOverflowException occurred in PresentationCore.dll.

Is there any way, how to increase limit for System.StackOverflowException?

[Here](https://skydrive.live.com/?mkt=cs-CZ#cid=23A0F69C907845C9&id=23A0F69C907845C9!1413) is the code example for download. After building and executing application, move the 
scrollbars to last activity with number 40 and exception should occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by increasing the size of the stack by using utility EDITBIN from VisualStudio

**editbin /STACK:6291456 "WpfApplication1.exe"**

Unfortunately it doesn't work in VisualStudio by adding into Post-Build section in project properties.
So I'd created the bat file, which is necessary to execute after build.

Answer (score 0):

I can run it without error and scroll to the very bottom - though it does get a bit slow - (64 bit machine, 16 gb memory).

You can allocate stack size on creation of a new thread, but I don't know how you could change the size for the default UI thread in your application...and if you can I'm not sure it'd be a good idea.

Besides, increasing the limit is only hiding the overall issue - which is why you need this in the first place - is anyone really going to nest 40 layers of complexity in a workflow?  It would be completely unwieldy and incredibly difficult to support.  Couldn't the logic be split into sub workflows, etc?

Comment: I know that increase of limits is not good idea and not solve my problem ultimately. I read about threads and stack overflow exception and there was that default size for stack is 1MB. If I can set it to 4th time more it would be enough.

Comment: I'm not sure you can - are you running 64 bit? If not that might be an option? As I said, it did work for me - albeit painfully slow as I scrolled

Comment: To raise an exception  is necessary to move position to last activity.

Comment: Yes 64bit and 8MB RAM

Comment: yep you're right, stack overflow on 40.  I haven't read anything about nested limitations, might be worth taking up with Microsoft